# How to make bootstrap progress bar highlight effect from left to right?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I really badly need your help...

I need to create a bootstrap progress bar with effect that will look like it's loading...

I don't like the bootstrap stripe effect loading...

I want a light effect that will highlight from left to right.

Here what I have done right now:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">

       <script type="text/javascript" src="/bootstrap/js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <style>

            .progress-bar.active, .progress.active .progress-bar {
            animation: reverse progress-bar-stripes 1s linear infinite;
        }

        .progress-bar-striped, .progress-striped .progress-bar {

            background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg,rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%,transparent 25%,transparent 100%,rgba(255,255,255,.15) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,.15) 75%,transparent 100%,transparent);
            background-image: linear-gradient(80deg,rgba(255,255,255,.5) 60%,transparent 25%,transparent 50%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 75%,transparent 75%,transparent);
            background-image: linear-gradient(90deg,rgba(255,255,255,.5) 15%,transparent 5%,transparent 10%,rgba(255,255,255,.3) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,.5) 95%,transparent 80%,transparent);
            background-image: #fff;
            background-size:100% 100%;




        }
        .progress-bar-gold {
            background-color: #f9e467; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
            background-color: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f9e467,#fdf4b5, #cb871b); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
            background-color: -o-linear-gradient(#f9e467,#fdf4b5, #cb871b); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
            background-color: -moz-linear-gradient(#f9e467,#fdf4b5, #cb871b); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
            background-color: linear-gradient(#f9e467,#fdf4b5, #cb871b); /* Standard syntax */
        }


      </style>
     <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar  progress-bar-gold  progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="50" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:50%">
        40%
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: try this http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_progressbar3&stacked=h

Comment: no not like that... I want to replace the bootstrap progress-bar-striped active effect...

That's static... no animation happening...

Comment: Is this https://css-tricks.com/examples/ProgressBars/ ?

Comment: Yes, but I want to replace the stripe loading effect, I want to change that into something light effect only...

It's like you are pointing a flashlight from the beginning to the end of the progress bar value in a little bit faster... 

I see that effect in some Computer Games loading effect. I hope you get what I mean...

Answer (score 0):

see this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/4s749o36/1/

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" origWidth="250px" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0px" id="myprogress">
    <span class="sr-only">45% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    var newWidth = $("#myprogress").attr("origWidth");
  $("#myprogress").animate({
                        width: newWidth
                    }, 1200);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time to answer. 

The loading effect is fine but I need to change the stripe loading effect to a light effect only... 

It's like you are pointing a FLASHLIGHT from left to right of the progress bar... something like that...

I hope you get what I mean...